# why all my favorite button color change when i click on one of them? - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, loops, button, use-state

I have an object called result, and I use map to loop the data inside result. I have a button in each data and its use to add the data to the database, after that the button color change. The problem is everytime I click the favorite button, all the button color in map got change too...

note: I m using if else to change the color (fa fa-heart and fa fa-heart-o)

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import "./App.css";
import DBRequest from "./DBRequest";

const AnimeList = ( { results } ) => {

const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);

const FavoriteState = (mal_id) => {
    var data_mal_id= {
        mal_id: mal_id
    }
    if(favorite){
        setFavorite(false);
        DBRequest(`/api/favorite/delete/${mal_id}`, "DELETE", data_mal_id);
    }else{
        setFavorite(true);
        DBRequest(`/api/favorite/post`, "POST", data_mal_id);
    }
}

return ( 
    <div className="anime-list flex overflow-auto no-scrollbar">
        { results && results.map((result) => (
            <div className="anime-preview p-3" key={ result.mal_id }>
                <div className="group w-48 h-72 relative cursor-none">
                    <img className="object-cover absolute h-full w-full z-10 filter group-hover:blur-sm group-hover:opacity-50" src={ result.image_url } alt="" />
                    <h2 className="absolute w-full top-0 text-left p-2 font-bold text-base z-20 pointer-events-none opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100">{ result.type }</h2>
                    <h2 className="absolute w-full top-1/4 text-center font-bold text-base z-20 pointer-events-none opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100">{ result.title }</h2>
                    <span id="heart">
                        <button onClick={ () => FavoriteState(result.mal_id) }> // all the color change when clicked
                            {favorite ? (
                               <i className="fa fa-heart absolute top-0 right-0 p-2 font-bold text-base z-20 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100" aria-hidden="true" > 
                               </i>
                            ) : (
                                <i className="fa fa-heart-o absolute top-0 right-0 p-2 font-bold text-base z-20 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100" aria-hidden="true" >
                                </i>
                            )}
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )) }
    </div>
);
}
```

sorry im new to reactjs and map thing and im lost..., and thanks for the answer

Comment: `favorite` is just a boolean, so if it's `true` it's true for all elements. Instead store the `mal_id` in the `favorite` state and compare to each iterated `result.mal_id`

Comment: @pilchard solved, thanksss :))